# Does stylesheet gets reloaded every time when UI gets re render in react native

Tags: react-native, stylesheet

I am trying to apply some logic which can detect orientation and as per the orientation change,once I get the orientation ,I will calculate width and height in stylesheet, here stylesheet is my another js file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your component in case of orientation change other wise It won't detect the change, or you can do it like that, add this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-orientation-locker`, You can lock the orientation with this, Using this package it won't let you change the orientation, It will show it like the one when app is opened.This will not disturb your UI.

Comment: cant lock orientation because its in requirement , and I am updating my component , even my rendering every time when I changed the orientation , but stylesheet is not reloading

Comment: I guess there maybe some style calling issue, You can add the updated width and height like this i.e 
```<View style= {[styles.demo, {width: 100, height: 20}]}/>```
Means update the width and height inside your component not in style sheet.